# CUDA & OpenCL GPUs compatibility in Cycles

Tags: rendering, gpu, hardware, opencl

I would like to add second GPU to my rig (currently I have GTX 1070). My budget allows two options: 1070 ti or Vega 64 (which seems to be much faster in Cycles) The question is: can a CUDA based GPU work with OpenCL card? This guy tested Radeon Pro Duo with GTX 1080, so it might be possible. I was actually kind of surprised about it. Can anyone confirm this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=To_N2xT6Xa8 (time 8:30)

Comment: According to the answer  to this question(https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31764/is-it-possible-to-use-different-cuda-capable-graphic-cards-to-render-simultaneou), you can mix and match models of the same type (amd/nvidia), but not across brands. In that video he is benchmarking performance against each other so not using both at the same time.

Comment: I've seen the answer to that question but it is like 2.5 years old and that is an eternity for hardware world and software updates. But actually at 8:30 he is benchmarking specifically GTX 1080 + Radeon against other cards. Well, I guess mixing amd/nvidia sounds like a lot of trouble in the end anyway.

Comment: OK, so I asked the guy an here is the conclusion: no AMD and nVidia with Cycles. Not yet. For using both cards Radeon Pro Render engine is needed (free for Blender...)

Comment: Good research, might want to write that up as an answer to make it easier for people to find in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Currenty, there is no support for AMD and nVidia GPUs to be used simultaneusly in Cycles (update is to arrive very soon from what I understand). One option is to use Radeon Pro Render engine developed by AMD. https://pro.radeon.com/en/software/prorender/